# Compilation errors with Make File creation

Tags: gcc, makefile

While running my make file which is as follows,

```
../bin/output : ../lib/libfun.a ../obj/main.o
                gcc ../main.o -L ../lib/ -lfun -o $@
../lib/libfun.a : ../obj/file_write.o ../obj/error.o
                ar -rc $@ $^
../obj/main.o   : ../src/main.c
                gcc -c $^ -o $@ -I ../include
../obj/file_write.o     : ../src/file_write.c
                gcc -c $^ -o $@ -I ../include
../obj/error.o  : ../src/error.c
                gcc -c $^ -o $@ -I ../include
```

I am getting error like

```
make: Warning: File `makefile' has modification time 2.2e+03 s in the future
ar -rc ../lib/libfun.a ../obj/file_write.o ../obj/error.o
ar: ../lib/libfun.a: No such file or directory
make: *** [../lib/libfun.a] Error 1
```

and sometimes

"*** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop"

Why is this happening? I gave correct Target,Pre-Requests and Command values whichever needed. Whats wrong in this?

Comment: Oh My God!. Just now figured it out. I am getting error like "*** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop"

Comment: Thanks to Mat for pointing out my mistake. Its really silly mistake :(

Comment: But in another make file i am getting ""*** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?). Stop" erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first error, make sure the `../lib` directory exists before trying to create a library in it. `ar` will return that error if the path doesn't exist.

For the second `make` syntax is strict: the commands after a target *must* be indented with a tab, not spaces.

```
target: deps
        command
#  ^ this here needs to be a tab character, not spaces
```